# Regex in RedirectRoute not working correctly

Tags: regex, google-app-engine, python-2.7, webapp2

I have looked into how to use a regex within a RedirectRoute using webapp2. I have tried formatting it the way it says to do so here: http://webapp-improved.appspot.com/guide/routing.html#the-url-template and I still cannot get my regex to work. Here is what I have:

`RedirectRoute('/book/<bookId:([0-9]+)><title:(.*)>',handlers.book,name='book')`

the call for this is:

```
self.redirect_to('book/%s_%s' %(bookId,title))
```

and an example of the url I am expecting is:

book/5907332378656768_The-Wizzard-of-Oz

When I run my app I get the following error:

Error: "Route named u'book/5907332378656768_The-Wizzard-of-Oz' is not defined.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
EDIT:
```

Hey everyone! Thanks to Brent's response I was able to fix the problem. 
I had to change `self.redirect_to('book/%s_%s' %(bookId,title))`
to the following: `self.redirect('book/%s_%s' %(bookId,title))`

Thank you everyone for your help!

Comment: `.*` will match any single character repeated zero or more times (e.g. `aaaa`). `.` means any single character. `*` means repeat previous item zero or more times. I suspect this is the part you have to rework to create an expression that would match a title.

Comment: @Brian - Er, not exactly true. `.*` also matches `abcd`. Maybe that's what you meant, but your example was misleading. `.` is better thought of as a character class that includes all characters except newlines.

Comment: My bad that's not the issue. Excuse the hasty comment :( Maybe something about escaping the forward slashes? `\/`

Comment: Thank you for the posts. I tried moving the second / into the regex and escaping it however that did not work either. The first one is proper the way it is. Thanks for trying! I stripped down the code to just the regex and used a python regex checker and It captured everything properly so I do not know what is going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Google search for `webapp2 error route "is not defined"` finds the [Webapp2 source code](http://webapp-improved.googlecode.com/hg/webapp2.py).  That error message is in the method `default_builder()` which is called from `redirect_to()`.  That method looks for the `name` field ('book' in this case).  Maybe you meant to call [redirect()](http://webapp-improved.appspot.com/api/webapp2.html#webapp2.redirect) instead?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can leave the parentheses off the patterns:

```
RedirectRoute('/book/<bookId:[0-9]+><title:.*>',handlers.book,name='book')
```

Comment: Thank you for your response I removed the parentheses and it didn't fix my problem but I do think it makes my code look cleaner.